# sql compact deployment 32 vs 64 bit files

Tags: sql-server-ce

I created an .SDF file ver 3.5 on 64 bit machine and am using visual studio express 2010 for a windows application. When I deploy the app to a 32 bit machine do I need to be concerened only with copying the proper 32 bit dlls or do I also need to create a different SDF file?

Answer (score 1):

You can include both the x64 and x86 dll files for all installtions - see this blog post: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html